# Is it possible to run Win32 executable on a virtual private server (VPS)?

Tags: php, c++, apache, binary

Is it possible to run Win32 executable on a virtual private server (VPS)?

I have created some .exe application from C++ code, and I need to let people on the internet run it, is it able to do so on a VPS? or I have to rent dedicated server?

I will take input from HTML form, pass it to PHP, and from PHP call 'system' to run my application with command line parameters, then get back the results to PHP, finally return the results to browser as HTML.

Comment: or it depends on the hosting provider to allow or disallow execution of binary on VPS? on dedicated server, surely we control it all.

Comment: Well, is the VPS going to run Windows?

Comment: any, windows or linux, as long as i can run my binary. i'm asking this question to decide which type of server to rent.

Comment: @Paul: Then it's not a programming question.

Comment: @Paul: If you have a Windows executable, then you need the Windows OS. Duh.

Comment: @Tom: it's programming related question :) i intended to post on superuser.com but i thought i would get the answer faster and more accurate on stackoverflow!

Comment: @Paul: The choice of which SE site you post to shall be based on which site is the _correct_ site for the topic of your question, not based on which site from which you think you'll get an answer quickest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem running a Windows executable on a Windows server as long as the executable is compatible with the Windows version used.

This is assuming that you have Administrator rights on your VPS, can install the application, and sort out any permissions problems that might arise at first.

Comment: tks for the answer pekka :) i choose vps coz it's much cheaper than dedicated server. but do we have full control down to system level?

Comment: @Paul you're welcome. Whether you have full control or not depends on the VPS, you'd have to ask the provider. (You should also ask them about whether your executable will run so you can pull out if it doesn't)

Comment: @Paul: "VPS" isn't a term that precisely describes some specific technology and server configuration. Server configurations vary wildly. You will need to ask your hosting provider for their opinion.